# Structurize multicell inside FPDF

Tags: fpdf

I have names received from database table:

```
ADEEB (staff) , ALISTER (staff), AMER (staff), AMIRABUBAKAR (staff), AMIRULHAFIZ (staff),
ANA (staff), ANDIKA (staff), ANDREW (staff), ARINA (staff), DIANADEWI (staff), DINA (staff),
DINIE (staff), DUDU (staff), DUNCAN (staff), ELIZABETH (staff), ERIC (staff), ERIN (staff), 
FAUZE(staff), FAZLY (staff),FELIZ (staff), HAYKAL (staff), IVANPINTO (staff), IVORY (staff), 
IVY (staff)
```

I want to create pdf file and print names like that inside fpdf using `multicell`:

```
function Mach($header, $header1, $lbl3)
{
    $this->Line(10,$this->GetY(),200,$this->GetY());
    //Times 12
    $this->SetFont('Times','B',12);
    //Background color
    $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
    //Title
    $this->Cell(50,10,"$header1",0,1,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Times','',12);
    $this->MultiCell(185,10,"$lbl3",1,1,'L');

}

$con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
{   
    $column_procStaff = '';

    $result6 = getProcessStaff($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
        if (!$result6) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }   
        $c=0;
        while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6))
        {  
            $procStaff = $row6['proc_staff'];
            if($c==0)
            {
                $column_procStaff .= $procStaff." (staff) ";
            } 
            else
            {
                $column_procStaff .= ", ".$procStaff." (staff)";
            }   
            $c++;
        }       
    $pdf->Mach("Process Name: $proc[$y]", $column_procStaff);
}
```

Also I want structure received names. Is there any way to do it to display smth like this:

```
ADEEB (staff),          ALISTER (staff),            AMER (staff),
AMIRABUBAKAR (staff),   AMIRULHAFIZ (staff),        ANA (staff), 
ANDIKA (staff),         ANDREW (staff),             ARINA (staff), 
DIANADEWI (staff),      DINA (staff),               DINIE (staff), 
DUDU (staff),           DUNCAN (staff),             ELIZABETH (staff),
ERIC (staff),           ERIN (staff),               FAUZE(staff), 
FAZLY (staff),          FELIZ (staff),              HAYKAL (staff),
IVANPINTO (staff),      IVORY (staff),              IVY (staff)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet using fPDF to write the names the way you want :

```
// Your data
$names= array("ADEEB (staff)", "ALISTER (staff)" ,"AMER (staff)" ,"AMIRABUBAKAR (staff)" ,"AMIRULHAFIZ (staff)", "ANA (staff)" ,"ANDIKA (staff)" ,"ANDREW (staff)" ,"ARINA (staff)" ,"DIANADEWI (staff)" ,"DINA (staff)", "DINIE (staff)" ,"DUDU (staff)" ,"DUNCAN (staff)" ,"ELIZABETH (staff)" ,"ERIC (staff)" ,"ERIN (staff)", "FAUZE(staff)" ,"FAZLY (staff),FELIZ (staff)" ,"HAYKAL (staff)" ,"IVANPINTO (staff)" ,"IVORY (staff)", "IVY (staff)");
// Number of column wanted
$nbColumn = 3;

// Computing width of columns
$maxWidth = 0;
foreach ($names as $n){
    $w = $pdf->GetStringWidth($n);
    if($maxWidth<$w){
        $maxWidth=$w;
    }
}
// add Margin
$maxWidth = $maxWidth + 10;

foreach ($names as $index => $n){
    // width, height, text, no norder, going to next line
    $pdf->Cell($maxWidth, 5, $n, 0, $index%$nbColumn==$nbColumn-1);
}
```